# Trouble for adding Admob banner ads

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

The code is working fine without admob part. When I add admob part code, it's shows error. How can I fix that?

I have added two parts of the code. One of that xml and others part have java code. That would be easier to find my problem.

Here is my xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/difficulty_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/difficulty_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.nayemuzzaman.kidsmemorize.ui.DifficultyView
                android:id="@+id/select_difficulty_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/time_difficulty_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-40dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
                android:background="@drawable/time_border"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

            <com.nayemuzzaman.kidsmemorize.ui.DifficultyView
                android:id="@+id/select_difficulty_4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/time_difficulty_4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/time_border"
                android:textSize="17sp" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/difficulty_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/difficulty_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.nayemuzzaman.kidsmemorize.ui.DifficultyView
                android:id="@+id/select_difficulty_2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/time_difficulty_2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-40dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
                android:background="@drawable/time_border"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

            <com.nayemuzzaman.kidsmemorize.ui.DifficultyView
                android:id="@+id/select_difficulty_5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/time_difficulty_5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/time_border"
                android:textSize="17sp" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/difficulty_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/difficulty_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.nayemuzzaman.kidsmemorize.ui.DifficultyView
                android:id="@+id/select_difficulty_3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/time_difficulty_3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-40dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
                android:background="@drawable/time_border"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

            <com.nayemuzzaman.kidsmemorize.ui.DifficultyView
                android:id="@+id/select_difficulty_6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/time_difficulty_6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/time_border"
                android:textSize="17sp" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margintoptendp"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_adUnitId" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Also i added java part code. thats also me be helpful for fix that.

DifficultySelectFragment.java

```
  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(Shared.context).inflate(R.layout.difficulty_select_fragment, container, false);
        Theme theme = Shared.engine.getSelectedTheme();

        DifficultyView difficulty1 = view.findViewById(R.id.select_difficulty_1);
        difficulty1.setDifficulty(1, Memory.getHighStars(theme.id, 1));
        setOnClick(difficulty1, 1);
       /* FIrstFragment fIrstFragment = new FIrstFragment();
        moveToFragment(fIrstFragment);*/


        DifficultyView difficulty2 =  view.findViewById(R.id.select_difficulty_2);
        difficulty2.setDifficulty(2, Memory.getHighStars(theme.id, 2));
        setOnClick(difficulty2, 2);

        DifficultyView difficulty3 =  view.findViewById(R.id.select_difficulty_3);
        difficulty3.setDifficulty(3, Memory.getHighStars(theme.id, 3));
        setOnClick(difficulty3, 3);

        DifficultyView difficulty4 =  view.findViewById(R.id.select_difficulty_4);
        difficulty4.setDifficulty(4, Memory.getHighStars(theme.id, 4));
        setOnClick(difficulty4, 4);

        DifficultyView difficulty5 =  view.findViewById(R.id.select_difficulty_5);
        difficulty5.setDifficulty(5, Memory.getHighStars(theme.id, 5));
        setOnClick(difficulty5, 5);

        DifficultyView difficulty6 =  view.findViewById(R.id.select_difficulty_6);
        difficulty6.setDifficulty(6, Memory.getHighStars(theme.id, 6));
        setOnClick(difficulty6, 6);

        animate(difficulty1, difficulty2, difficulty3, difficulty4, difficulty5, difficulty6);

        Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(Shared.context.getAssets(), "fonts/grobold.ttf");


        TextView text1 =  view.findViewById(R.id.time_difficulty_1);
        text1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        text1.setTypeface(type);
        text1.setText(getBestTimeForStage(theme.id, 1));

        TextView text2 =  view.findViewById(R.id.time_difficulty_2);
        text2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        text2.setTypeface(type);
        text2.setText(getBestTimeForStage(theme.id, 2));

        TextView text3 =  view.findViewById(R.id.time_difficulty_3);
        text3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        text3.setTypeface(type);
        text3.setText(getBestTimeForStage(theme.id, 3));

        TextView text4 =  view.findViewById(R.id.time_difficulty_4);
        text4.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        text4.setTypeface(type);
        text4.setText(getBestTimeForStage(theme.id, 4));

        TextView text5 =  view.findViewById(R.id.time_difficulty_5);
        text5.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        text5.setTypeface(type);
        text5.setText(getBestTimeForStage(theme.id, 5));

        TextView text6 = view.findViewById(R.id.time_difficulty_6);
        text6.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        text6.setTypeface(type);
        text6.setText(getBestTimeForStage(theme.id, 6));

        mAdview =  view.findViewById( R.id.adView );
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().tagForChildDirectedTreatment(true).build();
        mAdview.loadAd( adRequest );

        return view;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced my admob part through fragment .Also, I tested in Interstitial Ad admob with this code.

```
//For add of Admob app ID
        MobileAds.initialize(getContext(),
                "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");

        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(getContext());
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
        final AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                super.onAdLoaded();
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            }
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                super.onAdClosed();
                // mInterstitialAd.loadAd(request.build());
            }
        });

        mInterstitialAd.loadAd( request );
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your this question

**only no ad showing in layout**

There can be 2 possible reasons for ads not to show

1) If you have just created your ad mob ID than there is a huge chance you don't get any ad. Because when you create a new ad mob ID it takes sometimes to provide some ad to your ID

2) If first case is not valid, you have made ID 4-5 hours ago then make sure your ID is right. Mistakenly your are not using wrong ID or any typo.

Comment: @Waheed it's general answer, my problem isn't general. May be it's have to change something in my layout or other parts

Answer (score 0):

Add listener adview to find what's the error.

```
mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
          Toast.makeText(this, "ad loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }

    @Override
    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
        // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
          Toast.makeText(this, errorCode.toString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onAdOpened() {
        // Code to be executed when an ad opens an overlay that
        // covers the screen.
          Toast.makeText(this, "Ad opened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onAdLeftApplication() {
        // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ad left application", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onAdClosed() {
        // Code to be executed when when the user is about to return
        // to the app after tapping on an ad.
           Toast.makeText(this, "ad closed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});
```

Comment: check my updated answer and let me know are you getting any toast

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/difficulty_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/difficulty_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.nayemuzzaman.kidsmemorize.ui.DifficultyView
                android:id="@+id/select_difficulty_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/time_difficulty_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-40dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
                android:background="@drawable/time_border"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

            <com.nayemuzzaman.kidsmemorize.ui.DifficultyView
                android:id="@+id/select_difficulty_4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/time_difficulty_4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/time_border"
                android:textSize="17sp" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/difficulty_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/difficulty_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.nayemuzzaman.kidsmemorize.ui.DifficultyView
                android:id="@+id/select_difficulty_2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/time_difficulty_2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-40dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
                android:background="@drawable/time_border"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

            <com.nayemuzzaman.kidsmemorize.ui.DifficultyView
                android:id="@+id/select_difficulty_5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/time_difficulty_5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/time_border"
                android:textSize="17sp" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/difficulty_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/difficulty_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.nayemuzzaman.kidsmemorize.ui.DifficultyView
                android:id="@+id/select_difficulty_3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/time_difficulty_3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-40dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
                android:background="@drawable/time_border"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

            <com.nayemuzzaman.kidsmemorize.ui.DifficultyView
                android:id="@+id/select_difficulty_6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/time_difficulty_6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/time_border"
                android:textSize="17sp" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margintoptendp"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_adUnitId" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

Add  `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`  to your root layout

---

In Fragment:

```
private AdView mBannerAd;

mBannerAd = view.findViewById(R.id.adView);

AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .build();
        mBannerAd.loadAd(adRequest);
```

---

Add dependencies

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.6.0'
```